# Comparing uint64_t with an unsigned char*

Tags: c

I have this POC

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char *c = "This is ";
    uint64_t i;
    int j;
    i = c[7] | (c[6] << 8) | (c[5] << 16) | (c[4] << 24) | (c[3] << 32) | (c[2] << 40) | (c[1] << 48) | (c[0] << 56);
    printf("c value: '%s'\n", c);
    printf("Hex:");
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        printf(" %2x", c[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Is i equal to c? %d\n", 
        memcmp((unsigned char *)&i, "\x54\x68\x69\x73\x20\x69\x73\x20", 8)
    );
    return 0;
}
```

I have an `unsigned char *` (please note the white space at the end!) and an `uint64_t` which I'm filling in with the data from the `unsigned char *`.

Then I `memcmp` both vars and I'd expect to get `0`, but I get `-1`. Why is that?

I'm thinking it has something to do with how `c` is promoted in the bitwise operations, but I can't find exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: When you shift something like `c[0] << 56`, you must first typecast it to `uint64_t`, and then shift it.

Comment: Please compile with all warnings enabled before posting, the compiler will give you a bunch of clues already.

Comment: Are you sure you computer is Big Endian? Most aren't these days (certainly not Intel-based machines)

Comment: This isn't valid c++, please remove the c++ tag, also, c isn't c++.

Comment: @Wimmel You mean like this `( ((uint64_t)c[0]) << 56)`?

Comment: @username_unavailable I removed the `c++` flag, and I agree C is not C++. But why this code isn't valid C++?

Comment: Because it doesn't compile with any c++ compiler(From what I can see it is because in c++ a string literal is a const char* and gives an invalid conversion error).

Comment: @MatsPetersson That was the second reason I was getting wrong results (the first one being the missing cast). Thank you

Comment: @username_unavailable: Strictly speaking, it isn't valid C either. C string literals are of type`char[N]`. In the context of `unsigned char *c = "This is ";`, the `char[9]'` value of the literal decays to `char*`.  Attempting to assign a `char*` value to an `unsigned char*` object is a constraint violation. (gcc, for example, doesn't diagnose this by default, but it does issue a warning with `gcc -pedantic`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    unsigned char *c = "This is ";
    uint64_t i;
    int j;
    i = (uint64_t ) c[7] | ((uint64_t )c[6] << 8) | ((uint64_t )c[5] << 16) | ((uint64_t )c[4] << 24) | ((uint64_t )c[3] << 32) | ((uint64_t )c[2] << 40) | ((uint64_t )c[1] << 48) | ((uint64_t )c[0] << 56);
    printf("c value: '%s'\n", c);
    printf("Hex:");
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        printf(" %2x", c[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Printing i contents as they appear in memory \n");
    unsigned char *k=(unsigned char*)&i;
    for(int j = 0;j<8 ;j++)
        printf("%2x ",(unsigned) k[j]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Is i is equal to c? %d\n",
           memcmp(&i, "\x54\x68\x69\x73\x20\x69\x73\x20", 8)
           );
    return 0;
}
```

The output on my machine which is little endian is:

```
    c value: 'This is '
    Hex: 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20
    Printing i contents as they appear in memory 
    20 73 69 20 73 69 68 54
```

You can see the bytes are reversed when stored in memory. This should give you clue that if your PC is little endian, `i`'s least significant byte which is ' '  will be stored at the beginning in the memory address.

Comment: Deleted my answer as this is better. All I'd add is that `gcc -Wall` points out the error.

Comment: Indeed, I was missing both the cast AND the inverted order of bytes. Thank you